# Unable to Submit Case in Support in Salesforce

Tags: support, salesforce-support

I am trying to submit a case in salesforce but receiving the below error.

[image]

I had created a case before and now I am also not able to add a comment on that case as well which is weird. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a salesforce internal issue which has been resolved now.

[image]